# Consider mid of the week as starting week in DB2

Tags: db2

Is it possible to consider WEDNESDAY as start of the WEEK TUESDAY as end of the week in DB2 ? I used WEEK function however its considering MONDAY to SUNDAY as a week. Below is the query that brings in data for each week i.e. Monday to Sunday.

```
select column1, sum(column2) from TABLE where  
(readingdate >= DATE ('2020-04-01')  AND readingdate < DATE ('2020-04-30') + 
1 DAY)
group by column1, week(readingdate);
```

Below is the sample data

[image: data]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is not built-in date function for that. 
You need to create your own function, or expression.

also,  you need to think about the edge cases..   1st and last weeks of the year.

Here is a sample,  of what you can do..  I made assumptions like. Should I delay the week start?  or anticipate it ?  I chose to delay it.

```
    db2 "WITH D (myday) AS (
   values ('2019-12-30'), ('2019-12-31'), ('2020-01-01'), ('2020-01-02'), ('2020-01-03'),
          ('2020-01-04'), ('2020-01-05'), ('2020-01-06'), ('2020-01-07'), ('2020-01-08'), 
          ('2020-01-09'), ('2020-01-10'), ('2020-01-11'), ('2020-01-12'), ('2020-01-13'), 
          ('2020-01-14'), ('2020-01-15'), ('2020-01-16'), ('2020-01-17'), ('2020-01-18')
    )
select myday, varchar(dayname(myday), 10) name, dayofweek(myday) dayofweek,  week(myday) week, 
  CASE 
     WHEN dayofweek(myday) < 4 THEN ( CASE WHEN WEEK(myday) = 1 
                                        THEN week(date(myday) - dayofweek(myday) days) 
                                        ELSE WEEK(myday) -1 
                                      END )
     ELSE WEEK(myday)
  END week_for_Wed 

  from D"


MYDAY      NAME       DAYOFWEEK   WEEK        WEEK_FOR_WED
---------- ---------- ----------- ----------- ------------
2019-12-30 Monday               2          53           52
2019-12-31 Tuesday              3          53           52
2020-01-01 Wednesday            4           1            1
2020-01-02 Thursday             5           1            1
2020-01-03 Friday               6           1            1
2020-01-04 Saturday             7           1            1
2020-01-05 Sunday               1           2            1
2020-01-06 Monday               2           2            1
2020-01-07 Tuesday              3           2            1
2020-01-08 Wednesday            4           2            2
2020-01-09 Thursday             5           2            2
2020-01-10 Friday               6           2            2
2020-01-11 Saturday             7           2            2
2020-01-12 Sunday               1           3            2
2020-01-13 Monday               2           3            2
2020-01-14 Tuesday              3           3            2
2020-01-15 Wednesday            4           3            3
2020-01-16 Thursday             5           3            3
2020-01-17 Friday               6           3            3
2020-01-18 Saturday             7           3            3

  20 record(s) selected.
```

Look, that this year is interesting. (again, edge cases)  as Jan-1st  is Wed.  Maybe that's why you are asking for it..
So,  the previous year (2019) got reduced from 53 to 52 weeks.  (I am not sure if this is correct).
Again,  edge cases...

Use with care.

Comment: One question,  I assume Week_For_WED refers to the week number that date belongs to in 2020 . How can I group by based on this value?

Comment: That´s another question... But same way you group everything else..  Repeat the expression in the group by clause.  or use a CTE,  which will act as a temporary view ,  and group by column name specified in the CTE definition.

Answer (score 1):

This would do the job based on the few information provided

```
week(date('2020-05-20')- 3 days)
```

Comment: I just updated the question by adding my query . I tried your query but it does not bring the expected result.

Comment: describe what you need and provide all details - do not let us guess!